# SQLite: select strftime('%m %y', dateField) as myDate

Tags: sql, sqlite

i try to convert a MySQL-query into SQLite but fail with this:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(dateField,'%M %Y') AS myDate FROM ...

SELECT *, strftime('%m %y', dateField) as myDate FROM ...
```

The output of myDate is empty, it only works if i only use %m OR %y but not both.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: And if you use `strftime('%m %Y', datefield)` ?

Comment: Works! Thanks Gordon!